# Cannot find several types of authentication on IIS7 in Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

I have a deployed and correctly working ASP.NET MVC3 application on IIS7 in Windows Server 2008.

Now I want to implement some authentication policy and my choice is Windows authentication (the website works in a Intranet). Unfortunately when I go to the IIS7 in the Authentication section of my web application I just find three types of authentication:

Anonymous

ASP.NET Impersonation

Forms

Digest and Windows authentication are missing. In googled a bit and I found that this might happen just in Vista because you have to explicitly activate the other types of authentication through the OS control panel. This however does not apply for Windows Server 2008.

May you please help me with this issue?

Thanks

Francesco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install add Windows Authentication to the IIS role through server manager if you didn't do it previously.

Screen shots can be found [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/zroiy/archive/2008/08/17/missing-windows-authentication-provider-for-iis-7-on-windows-server-2008.aspx) if you're having a hard time figuring it out.

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly! Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to vote you up. I expected the reputation I gained in stackoverflow to be transferred here as well.